# Ice Melting with a Twist

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, buoyancy

#### The Question

> There are three ice cubes floating in three different cups of water.
>
> - In the first cup, the ice cube has **a pocket of air** inside.
> - In the second cup, the ice cube has **a pocket of liquid water** inside.
> - In the third cup, the ice cube has **a metal pellet** inside.
>
> How does the level of water in each cup change as the ice cubes melt?
>
> (a) no change, no change, no change
>
> (b) up, no change, down
>
> (c) down, no change, up
>
> (d) no change, no change, down
> (e) down, no change, down

---

### My Work

So, I know that if you have just normal ice, the level of water in each cup will be the same as the ice will displace the same volume of water when melted (since the ice has a lower density). I do not really know how to apply that knowledge when there are different materials within the ice.

My first instinct is that the ice will still be displacing how much it weighs, but the pocket of air will not add to the level of the water. And, I am not sure if the metal pellet or water will act in the same way as ice because they are both denser than ice. Any help?

EDIT: Also, I think it is looking at the water level after it melts. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework question so I will only give conceptual hints:

The ice can melt at both external and internal interfaces.

What determines the rate of melting at an interface?

Comment: It is a homework question from a statics unit. The rate of melting is based on the temperature difference, the surface area of the interface, and specific heat.

Comment: Why would the rate of melting matter at all in this problem?

Comment: It is an inhomogeneous medium. The rate of melting will determine how much melting occurs where

Comment: Another constraint is that the air pocket is a compressible medium, so liquid melting there changes the air pressure. Internal melting in other cases creates stress which can lead to cracking.

Comment: Water that melts in the air pocket won't change the specific gravity of the ice block whereas water that melts at the outer interface will.

Comment: The external interface is also not uniform. There will be different melting rates at the upper portion (ice-air) and lower portion (ice-water). This will change the shape of the ice and thus how much of the surface area is above and below which in turn affects the rate of melting of each portion. It becomes a very complex coupled problem though at least each ice block has the externals in common unless at some point the block flips.

Comment: @PaulChilds I think that the melting interface will not matter b/c I think it is asking after it melts. Sry for the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Before the ice cube melts, the contents of the pocket are displacing a quantity of water that has the same mass.  Imagine a fixed volume, and guess the mass of that size for air, for water, and for metal.

After the ice melts, the ice itself doesn't change the level (as you say).  So the only thing that can change it is the substance inside.

If you put that air, that water, or that metal into the container and let the water come to equilbrium, does it displace the same amount of water or a different amount of water?  If it displaces more, the water level will rise.  If it displaces less, the water level will fall.

P.S.  When I first looked at this, I thought the answer would basically be linear with the density of the inclusion (one goes one way, one goes the other, and the third in between).  That's not the case.  It was much more subtle and confused me for a bit.

Comment: But the question does not ask for the water level *after* it melts but *as* it melts

Comment: @PaulChilds, You're quite right.  I hadn't thought of it that way. I interpreted it as "the change you get when the pocket melts, releasing the contents."  Otherwise, *as* it melts is undefined, since the pocket could be breached at any point during the melting.